# Is writing to a by-value function parameter good style?

Tags: c++

I always heard the rule that changing a parameter that was given to the function by value is bad coding style. Instead it is preferred to create a copy that is modified.

But I think in the following case it would be acceptable to change the function parameters. What do you think is the best way to do it?

```
Point3f GetWorldPoint(int x, int y)
{
    x = saturate(x, 0, width);
    y = saturate(y, 0, height);

    ...
}

template<typename T>
T saturate(T val, T min, T max) {
    return std::min(std::max(val, min), max);
}
```

Comment: I believe compilers optimize it out, so it's all personal preference.

Comment: What I think the best way to do it is my opinion. Which makes this primarily opinion based. Although *obviously* returning by value is better than modifying references.

Comment: agree with @AngeloGeels compiler can do optimization So it is a personal choice, but In general you should avoid copies if you don't need it.

Comment: With small types (typically value types), I would avoid passing by reference, so that the interface clarifies that there is no side effects on the passed variable. Reasons to choose for references are usually optimization (save copy time and saving memory in a lot of cases) or convenience reasons.

Comment: This is very much a matter of opinion or preference. It's not something I've seen a lot of discussion on. You can do it, of course, but it feels wrong, as though it's going to make your code harder to follow.

Comment: @fardjad, abort: the question is explicitely about by-value parameters, so no side effect, only local copies of parameters are modified.

Comment: Not related to the question at all, the function that you call saturate is usually called clamp.

Comment: The question is not about references. The question is, given that the parameters will be passed by value, is it "bad style" to modify that? To me, that's a very strange question, but I think it's good to stay focussed on the original question.

Comment: "I always heard the rule that changing a parameter that was given to the function by value is bad coding style" Here's my opinion: it is not bad coding style. It is perfectly fine. The parameter is your own local copy. You can do with it what you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some objection with using

```
Point3f GetWorldPoint(int x, int y)
{
    x = saturate(x, 0, width);
    y = saturate(y, 0, height);

    ...
}
```

Because even semantically, x and y aren't the same before and after the saturate function (they are saturated after all).  In more complex situations, this might become confusing.  Of course, in obvious functions, it's still straightforward that after saturate, you are now using the saturated x.

Anyway, there is nothing wrong with

```
Point3f GetWorldPoint(int origX, int origY)
{
    int x = saturate(origX, 0, width);
    int y = saturate(origY, 0, height);

    ...
}
```

It is clearer and an optimizing compiler will create similar code in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to stick my neck out here and say it's fine.  For example:

```
template<class T>
Matrix4x4<T> Transpose(Matrix4x4<T> m)
{
    return m.Transpose();
}
```

or

```
template<class T>
Matrix4x4<T> Transpose(Matrix4x4<T> const & m)
{
    Matrix4x4<T> n(m);

    return n.Transpose();
}
```

Which is more concise?

Comment: I am a little torn in this specific example. If I am not mistaken there is a real difference between the two codes. As RVO can not be applied to a function parameter the first one will result in transpose -> move/copy while the second one will result in copy -> transpose. This might make no difference for matrices but is something to keep in mind.

Comment: I think it's fine to pass by value anything you're going to make a copy of anyway.  I remember reading or seeing Scott Meyers talking about it, though my recollection is only dim.